# Convert audio to OGG format via Terminal

Tags: terminal, applications, audio, file-conversion

Is there an app or a method that I can use from Terminal to convert audio files to the OGG format?

I know about `afconvert` but that doesn't provide the `ogg` format that I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ogg is a container format. It typically uses the Vorbis audio codec. You can [download a static build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and use the bundled `libvorbis` encoder:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5 output.ogg
```

According to the [Vorbis encoding guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide), the quality range is from 0–10, where 10 is the highest quality and 3–6 are a good range to try. In the above example we used 5 as quality.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this question a couple of times, this is what worked for me:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -i foo.mp3  -strict -2 -acodec vorbis -ac 2 -aq 50 foo.ogg
```

Source: http://infoheap.com/ffmpeg-convert-mp3-to-ogg-on-mac/

Answer (score -1):

have a look at sox and ffmpeg they should do it.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -acodec ogg file.ogg
```

i think that was the command i used. not sure used to be a long time ago.

also have a look here why you probably wont do a conversion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/147944/bulk-batch-convert-mp3-files-to-ogg-via-command-line

Comment: `ogg` is not a valid FFmpeg encoder. Your command does not work.